# How can I arrange coloured triangles in hexagons so that they dont touch each other?

Tags: geometry, permutations, triangles, combinatorial-geometry

Based on the fact that:

1. There are 120 non-cyclical permutations of {1,2,3,4,5,6}
2. Each permutation could be represented by a hexagon with 6 triangles of different colours; e.g.,

[image]

Is it possible to write a formula or algorithm (function) to arrange (in a tessellation) these 120 hexagons in such a way that each triangle of colour is completely separated from its own colour i.e. it is surrounded by 12 triangles of colours that are not it's own colour. e.g., like this:

[image]

So that the result would be 720 Triangles composing 120 hexagons with unique non-cyclical permutations where no triangle touches (either at the point or at the side) a triangle of the same colour.

To clarify - If one colouring is a rotation of another then it is not part of the 120 permutations that are permitted to compose the final pattern in which all unique permutations of colours are allowed to be used and should be used only once.

[image]

Can the above pattern be generated ad infinitum?
Can we frame this in terms of colouring a 12 regular infinate graph?

Comment: For me, it isn't clear how the 720 triangles are arranged. Could you give a reference ? Besides, could you give information about the reason why you are interested by the neighborhood constraint (no triangle of the same colour) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for your interest please see the updated post for an example of what the triangle arrangement might look like. I am interested in the neighborhood constraint because visually I find it more appealing, and I think it makes the problem more interesting.

Comment: I assume that by "noncyclical" you mean "up to rotation". So if one coloring is a rotation of another you don't count it again. In your final pattern, are you allowed to use any one of the six rotations of each kind? Please [edit] to clarify. Don't respond in a comment.

Comment: It seems to me that it must be possible to write a computer program that would generate a pattern of the type shown above does anyone know how one would go about doing this?

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you are thinking of these hexagons as tiles that you lay edge to edge, in which case the spot where three hexagons meet does not contain such a hexagon tile (as the six triangles there belong to different tiles), or if you are looking at a triangular grid where every vertex with 6 triangles meeting is considered the centre of one of those hexagons.